# accessing additional parameters inside resource::collection

Tags: php, laravel

i have resource which returns the user quiz status it looks something like this

```
$users = Users::with('UserQuiz')->get();
return response(['users'=> UserResource::collection($users ) ]);
```

inside the resource i need to return user information and their quizzes

```
$passedQuizzes = [] ;
foreach($this->UserQuiz as $userQuiz )
{
   if($userQuiz->score > 50 )
      $passedQuizzes[] = $userQuiz  ; 
}


$totalQuiz = Quiz::count();


return [

  'id' => $this->id , 
  'name' => $this->name , 
  'email' => $this->email , 
  
  'quiz'=>[
      'total'=> $totalQuiz , 
      'passed' => count($passedQuizzes)
  ]
  
];
```

i need to show the total number of quiz and how many this user has passed ... so i need an extra query inside my resource which is not a good idea considering im running the same query over and over

so i need to somehow inject the `totalQuiz` from controller to resource so  , i've red about additional in the doc so i guess it should be something like

```
$users = Users::with('UserQuiz')->get();
$totalQuiz = Quiz::count();

return response(['users'=> UserResource::collection($users )->additional(['totalQuiz' => $totalQuiz ]) ]);
```

but i have no idea how to access this additional data inside resource
i want to be able to do something like

```
return [

  'id' => $this->id , 
  'name' => $this->name , 
  'email' => $this->email , 
  
  'quiz'=>[
      'total'=> $this->additional->totalQuiz , 
      'passed' => count($passedQuizzes)
  ]
  
];
```

this is a very common problem i wonder why there are not many answers online about this problem

this is the only thing i can find online which doesnt seem to have a suitable answer

[Additional data in Laravel Resource](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59438633/5796284)

Comment: You will have to overwrite the constructor of your Resource to allow more arguments, or create an own static method that creates the resource and adds the other arguments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code adds a static method to your Resource. This method can take as many additional paramters as you'd like. I added the `$totalQuiz` param for demonstration purpose.

```
   //add static variable
   public static $totalQuiz;

   /**
     * Create a new anonymous resource collection.
     *
     * @param  mixed  $resource
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Resources\Json\AnonymousResourceCollection
     */
    public static function customCollection($resource, $totalQuiz)
    {
        self::$totalQuiz = $totalQuiz;

        return tap(new AnonymousResourceCollection($resource, static::class), function ($collection) {
            if (property_exists(static::class, 'preserveKeys')) {
                $collection->preserveKeys = (new static([]))->preserveKeys === true;
            }
        });
    }
```

You can then create the Resource with this new static method instead of the static `UserResource::collection($users)` method.

```
UserResource::customCollection($users, $totalQuiz);
```